# Install .Net 4.5 on Windows 10 (4.5 and 4.6 versions are missing)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, windows-10

I cannot install .NET Framework 4.5 nor 4.6 on windows 10

The situation is as follows:
On my machine I had

- Windows 10 installed (upgraded from Windows 8.1)
- Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition
- Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

.Net frameworks that were visible in VS2013 were 2.0, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2
VS2015 Was not used so I cannot tell which versions were visible but I guess they were the same.

Yesterday I had some problems with TDD.Net installation (in was not visible in VS2013 but only in VS2015) I was not using VS2015 so I decided to uninstall it.

After VS2015 uninstall .Net 4.5 is **gone**. I cannot build my code without changing the projects frameworks. VS2013 after loading my solutions is repeating that 4.5 is missing.

I cannot install 4.5 because windows 10 gives an error saying the newer version is already installed.
I cannot install 4.6 because windows 10 gives error saying that this version is already installed (but it is not visible in VS2013!)

Hot to fix it? Is there some workarounds? 
How to repair  4.5 and 4.6 installation in windows 10?

Comment: It's more likely that your Visual Studio installation needs repairing / a "targeting pack" got uninstalled that shouldn't have been rather than you having a missing .net Framework

Comment: Hi Rob, Thanks for help, after repairing visual studio 2013 installation all targeting frameworks are back to normal. Thanks. Can you put your comment as an answer?

Comment: If somebody thinks this question is not useful or not clear and marks it down should give an explanation...

Answer (score 0):

you can download .net 4.5 from this link https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net45/
then extract file with 7zip so copy file in build and paste in program files x86 in dotnet

Comment: Reading the question reveals that OP has probably already tried this and already has the relevant versions of .NET Framework already installed and something else has gone wrong.